Using endDelimiter with one-line SQL statements
I'm trying to make the following code work in my deployment:
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset test:1 endDelimiter:/

CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM XXXX FOR XXX;
/
GRANT EXECUTE ON XXXX TO XXXX;
/
--rollback not required; 

The code snippet above results in an error

ORA-00933: SQL not properly ended

The deployment tool needs the code from procedures, functions and triggers to be in separate .sql files from that of grants, create, replace, etc.
My goal is to standardize the use of the delimiter / for all files.
Is there a way to achieve using endDelimiter:/ with semi-colons or would it be better to just use endDelimiter with those pieces of code which have stored logic like procedures, functions, etc?
Thanks

If you've changed the delimiter to /, don't you just need to remove the semicolons from those two statements? (You'd still have them in PL/SQL blocks, but those re terminated by / anyway...)


Is there a way to achieve using endDelimiter:/ with semi-colons

No, either use / or ;. You cannot use both to terminate SQL statements.
If you are mixing SQL and PL/SQL statements then only use / as the statement delimiter because ; will terminate statements within the PL/SQL block and you do not want Liquibase splitting the script on those.
You code should be:
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM XXXX FOR XXX
/
GRANT EXECUTE ON XXXX TO XXXX
/
DECLARE
  -- Example of a PL/SQL block
  something BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/

The SQL statements must not be followed by ;. The PL/SQL statements must be terminated by ;.
